Could Biden's supreme court reform ideas have any chance to happen, or is it empty talk to please his base?
Biden has been talking about Supreme court reforms, such as adding term limits and ethics restraints.
Some of them, like term limits, would almost certainly require a constitutional amendment.  Other's are a bit more ambiguous as to rather it can be legislated by congress without an amendment or not, but in either case it would need heavy congressional support to happen, and it doesn't seem likely that Biden can get it.
So in short, is there any chance at all that the talk about supreme court reform would actually happen?  or is it empty rhetoric to please his base?

Until we know exactly what he is proposing and the makeup of the senate and house at that time all we can do is make guesses.

I also wonder if this is too speculative. One would really need to give proponents of ideas some slack in this regard. Maybe based on the past how often would Democrats have had the majority to implement these changes? But then the future may be different, do one doesn't really know. Would we have guessed 10 years ago what is now the case?

A question listing things Biden has explicitly suggested (if there are any) and asking whether they'd require amendments or just a new law would be answerable and on topic.  A question about "things Biden has suggested" as a blanket category, or one about "would Congress pass this" ought to be closed.

Under the current US constitution, Supreme Court ethics can be enforced through Congressional impeachment, just like ethics for Presidents, same enforcers, same procedures, same vague rules and political bias.  For example a non-MAGA hrep majority (acting as a grander jury) can file charges against supposedly bribed justices and then try them before the Senate Jury, given another non-MAGA majority.
Term limits pose both political and democratic problems, because as terms expire, seats become vacant at predictable times that can be targeted by parties scheduling their strongest Senate and Presidential election campaigns to try holding those posts when appointing the new judges.  More viable would be a Senate procedural rule to never approve more than 3 SCOTUS judges suggested by any one president, thus spreading out the creation of majorities to give both parties a chance, though as long as more than half of presidents are Republican, there will be a long term tendency for Republican judges (the past 56 years has had 6 republicans and 4 democrats), but at least such a rule would prevent any one president (like Reagan or Clinton) from fully packing the court.  A 25 year old judge appointed by Nixon would be quite old by now, so no point looking further back.  If Harris of Kennedy Jr. win this year, they would get a fresh quota of max 3, but if Biden or Trump get a second term, they will still be working in the remains of their 3 judge limits and may have to leave some seats vacant until the 2029-2032 president gets to appoint a fresh quota of max 3.
Also some of the controversial decisions of the current SCOTUS can be overridden by congressional lawmaking, such as a general appointments law filling in the details of the appointments clause (differently than the Judge Cannon reading) and a general regulations law reserving to congress the ability to selectively undo delegated regulatory decisions such as the approval of certain drugs or the inspection of fishing vessels.  A law granting more power to congress would have great incentives for passing.  Some of this could also be done as EOs giving POTUS the power to directly override lower executive officers in such matters.

Under the current congress enforcing ethics through impeachment is impossible as any sort of impeachment related matter is going to occur along party lines ensuring that nothing will ever happen. This question isn't asking about what can be done now but if future changes are possible.

The question is also asking about Biden's ideas.  Are these general ideas, or are they based on information/quotes from Biden?

Also - term limits scheduled similarly to the Senate, such that one Justice's term ends every two years, means that each President would get to appoint two per term (ignoring unexpected vacancies).  There's then no timing benefit to when one party holds power (unlike now and unlike your proposal).

Truly huge excesses (unlike political disagreement) may inspire enough outrage to allow a bipartisan impeachment, as envisioned by the founders.  For example Cannon ruling to invalidate most appointments of special counsels, including some past appointments of republican ones .  Or a certain SCOTUS judge receiving lots of money from one litigant.  Then there's cases of judges that are truly awful in other ways, such as sexually exploiting defendants or stealing confiscated drugs for their own habit (such judges really were ousted in recent years, but they may have been state judges).

Note that my proposal of 3 appointments per president (even two term presidents) was meant to be a reasonable limit for the current situation with geriatric life time judges.  Appointing two 6 year judges per 4 year presidential term would reduce the court to just 3 judges and require a constitutional amendment, not just a senate majority to amend procedures.

@jb_dk - I just used the Senate as an example of overlapping terms.  Clearly, they'd have to be longer than six years each to maintain a reasonably sized court.  18 year terms, with one term expiring every two years would do it for the current size.  But unless this was Biden's proposal, it's irrelevant to the question as asked.
